# What German beers are similar to Belgian abbey beers?

Tags: german-beers, belgian-beers

I visit Germany a lot (Augsburg, Bavaria) and I can't seem to find a beer that would be similar to Belgian beers, for example to [Grimbergen blonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimbergen_(beer)).

So far the closest I've come is kellerbier but still it's nothing like a Belgian beer.

Is there some beer type or specific brand that manufactures beer similar to Belgian ones?

Comment: Can you elaborate what characteristics of Belgian blondes you miss in German Keller- and Weizenbeers?

Comment: @AltbierisnotOldBeer it’s hard for me to explain but I guess some kind of fruity flavor. German beer is too bland for me in comparison to Belgian beers

Comment: There might be some beers which would resemble Belgians. I remember [Ayinger Frühlingsbier](https://www.ayinger.de/cms/index.php/fruehlingsbier.html) was very fresh but it's only available in the spring.

Comment: In Germany most beers are brewed according to the so called German Purity law which does not allow to use anything except water, barley, hops and yeast. And in Belgian they are allowed put everything in the beer (f.e. _Hoegaarden Witbier_ is made with coriander and orange peel - unthinkable heresy in Germany). And different hops may play a role too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find a German-style beer that is similar to Belgian beer (as Germany-style beers are low fermented ones, while Belgian beer are top fermented ones).
But recently it has become easy to find a German brewery that brews a Belgian beer, e.g. [Camba](http://www.camba-bavaria.de/en/international-beers/), as well as some IPAs and stouts.

Comment: What do you call German style beers? Pilsener? Weizen (which is somewhat similar to Belgian witbiers) is top-fermented, Altbier is top-fermented, Kölsch is top-fermented. And the question is btw not about a German-style beers but about German beers.

Comment: @ Altbier is not Old Beer  You are right. But when I think about German-style beers, I start thinking about helles, dunkel, keller, bock,...